Ratio of Sides with Given Angles (30° and 50°)
I have trouble solving this math problem my teacher gave me: In the triangle $\triangle ABC$, given that  $\angle A = 30$ and $\angle B = 50$, prove that the sides of the triangle satisfy the following ratio:
$a = \frac{c^2 - b^2}{b}$

Let me try.
From the law of cosines, we have:
$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos{100^{\circ}}\Rightarrow\frac{c^2-b^2}{b}=a\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)-2a\cos{100^{\circ}}$$
We also know from the law of sines that:
$$\frac{a}{\sin{30^{\circ}}}=\frac{b}{\sin{50^{\circ}}}\Rightarrow\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\sin{30^{\circ}}}{\sin{50^{\circ}}}$$
Thus,
$$\frac{c^2-b^2}{b}=a\left(\frac{\sin{30^{\circ}}}{\sin{50^{\circ}}}\right)-2a\cos{100^{\circ}}$$
$$\frac{c^2-b^2}{b}=a\left(\frac{\sin{30^{\circ}}}{\sin{50^{\circ}}}-2\cos{100^{\circ}}\right)$$
$$\frac{c^2-b^2}{b}=a\left(\frac{\sin{30^{\circ}}-2\sin{50^{\circ}}\cos{100^{\circ}}}{\sin{50^{\circ}}}\right)$$
$$\frac{c^2-b^2}{b}=a\left(\frac{\frac{1}{2}-2\sin{50^{\circ}}\cos{100^{\circ}}}{\sin{50^{\circ}}}\right)$$
Using the trig. identity $\sin{a}\cos{b}=\frac{\sin{(a+b)}+\sin{(a-b)}}{2}$:
$$\frac{c^2-b^2}{b}=a\left(\frac{\frac{1}{2}-2\left(\frac{\sin{150^{\circ}}+\sin{\left(-50^{\circ}\right)}}{2}\right)}{\sin{50^{\circ}}}\right)$$
$$\frac{c^2-b^2}{b}=a\left(\frac{\frac{1}{2}-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\sin{50^{\circ}}\right)}{\sin{50^{\circ}}}\right)$$
$$\frac{c^2-b^2}{b}=a\left(\frac{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}+\sin{50^{\circ}}}{\sin{50^{\circ}}}\right)$$
$$\frac{c^2-b^2}{b}=a\left(\frac{\sin{50^{\circ}}}{\sin{50^{\circ}}}\right)$$
$$\boxed{\frac{c^2-b^2}{b}=a}$$
